# Using a custom com.android.internal.R.layout.preference

Tags: android, layout, preference

Is there any way of setting the layoutResId of android.preference.Preference? I need to replace com.android.internal.R.layout.preference with something more than a ListView. (I want a PreferenceActivity in another view, and for it to inflate the hierarchy of preferences in that view instead of only showing the default ListView). Through PreferenceActivity I can get the PreferenceManager, but PreferenceManager.getPreferenceScreen is package-private. PreferenceScreen.setLayoutResId can change the ResId I want, but I can't get at it. If I could, would changing this work or would it break things?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334194/custom-preferencescreen-with-clickable-buttons

Answer (score 1):

You can call `setContentView` on a `PreferenceActivity` as long as there is a `ListView` somewhere in the layout with an ID of `android.R.id.list` (or `@android:id/list` from XML). This will be the target into which preferences are inflated. You are free to add whatever other views you'd like as long as this requirement is met.