# How to customize PreferenceScreen?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have the following hierarchy:

`PreferenceScreen`

-----`PreferenceCategory`

------------`PreferenceScreen`

-----------------`EditTextPreference`

-----------------`Preference`

-----------------`Preference`

The last three preferences appear in form of a list as `PreferenceActivity` comes from `android.app.ListActivity`.

Is there a way to put these preferences in a single row like

---

### EditTextPreference || Preference || Preference

---

and each of them will remain clickable and separate as before?

Comment: The point behind `PreferenceScreen` is to have a UI that matches the Settings app and other apps that use `PreferenceScreen`. Since you do not seem interested that, why not create your own preference UI from scratch? Then, you can make it look like whatever you want.

Comment: Yes CW is right..You can´t set preferences side by side, in fact that´s a thing the API should make it possible. But I had a similar problem and followed this link which gives You an idea how about to do it...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108609/android-creating-custom-preference

Comment: @CommonsWare - Actually I'm interested in using `PreferenceScreen`, I just wanted to know if it is possible to be done because it is exactly what I'm aiming for. 



@Opiatefuchs - I have already read that thread, I made custom layout for one of the `Preferences` but that led me to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334194/custom-preferencescreen-with-clickable-buttons) unresolved question. :)